# How to proper configure timezones for cqlsh and cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

**How to proper configure cassandra/cqlsh to use the same timezone as my system?**

I'm new to cassandra and going my first stepts. I'm trying to understand the way cassandra works and especially trying to verify my table-layout.

I had trouble when trying to **SELECT rows FILTERED BY timestamp**. I noticed, that it is caused by a timezone problem I have to solve first.

```
DROP TABLE measuring;
CREATE TABLE measuring (
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    sensor VARCHAR,
    value VARCHAR,
    unit VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (sensor, timestamp)
) 
WITH gc_grace_seconds = 0
AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);

INSERT INTO measuring (timestamp, sensor, value, unit) 
VALUES ('2017-07-18 16:05:21', '01-a', '1', 'Celsius');

SELECT * FROM measuring;
```

**Output:**

```
cqlsh:keyspace> SELECT * FROM measuring;

 sensor | timestamp                       | unit    | value
--------+---------------------------------+---------+-------
   01-a | 2017-07-18 14:05:21.000000+0000 | Celsius |     1

(1 rows)
cqlsh:keyspace>
```

So I inserted `'2017-07-18 16:05:21'` and getting `2017-07-18 14:05:21.000000+0000` back from cqlsh.

My actual timezone is UTC+2 (Germany).

My debian:

```
root@mydebianmachine:~# date
Do 20. Jul 16:03:16 CEST 2017
```

---

**Update:** Completely reworked the question, because it seems like the ghost I was looking for is called timezone.

Comment: In cassandra table is defined by your query requirement. First list all your select query that your want to perform.

Comment: Describe your query for specifically like you want to select last two days data

Comment: I tried your example and it works as expected.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam For me this means cassandra is not useable if you're planning a future project where you can't predict what queries you need? I want to be able to select timespans.

Comment: @Mandraenke After I sent this question, I did it again with the same code as posted. It worked just like you're saying. I dropped and created the table again using the same code and it doesn't work anymore. See the screenshot. What's going on?

Comment: Another strange result-set: https://i.imgur.com/6eM0y8t.png